# Local field such that the value group of $K^\text{perf}$ ( perfect closure of $K$) is $\bigcup_{n\geqq1}(1/p^n) \Bbb{Z}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, local-fields

Let $K$ be a local field of positive characteristic.
I'm looking for a $K$ which satisfies the following condition.

- Value group of $K^\text{perf}$ (perfect closure of $K$) is $\bigcup_{n\geqq1}(1/p^n) \Bbb{Z}$.

$K$ should be like the form $ \Bbb{F}_q((t))$, so I need to determine $q$.

Comment: I think that using Eisenstein polynomials will show that, for every local field, the value group of $K^\text{sep}$ is $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Sorry, it was typo. Perfect closure was is my question.

Comment: Then the question is trivial; take $q = p$.